# how to create right click event for touch screen devices using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, web-applications, touchscreen

in my web application i have right click event menu on my data grid.

now problem is when user open same page on touchscreen device user not able to access the right click menu

how to connect touch screen event to JQuery right click?

Comment: Probably not going to happen the way you intend. You need to bind to `touchStart`, but that'll be a problem if the user has to scroll anywhere within your device. what you probably want to do is make it a multi-panel layout where the 'data grid' is always visible as a column within the panel layout.

Comment: sorry i didnt understand

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I understand your problem, but how would you recognize right click on a touch screen?

My suggestion is that you can create a "config button" in your data-grid which a user may press to trigger your javascript right click event.

Comment: ok so you mean there is no option to right click on touchscreen :)

Comment: Well, at least I don't know how to achieve it... Here it's written you may achieve it in windows tablets => http://www.andyrathbone.com/2012/03/12/how-do-i-right-click-on-a-touch-screen-tablet/, but what would you do with the others? Check any tablet in the market? Well, I think the cheapest solution is the proposed above, ;)